# Aggregating Data according to name and time in python

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a set of data of about 200 bike stations recorded every minute.

I am trying to aggregate the data so that I have the result for each station in 15 min intervals.

the data looks something like this right now

```
          Description                                          timestamp             BikeAvailable  
         28707 Neumühlen / Övelgönne                         2019-12-16 13:38:05          False  
         28703 Fischersallee / Bleickenallee                 2019-12-16 13:38:05          False  
         28702 Bleickenallee / Kinderkrankenhaus Altona      2019-12-16 13:38:05           True      
         28704 Eulenstraße / Große Brunnenstraße             2019-12-16 13:38:05          False  
         28705 Große Rainstraße/Ottenser Hauptstraße         2019-12-16 13:38:05           True
```

"28707 Neumühlen / Övelgönne " would be for example the name of a station.

I currently used

```
dftest = df.groupby(['timestamp', 'Description'])
```

to group the variable and am hoping to eventually end up using

```
dftestR = dftest.resample('15min').last()
```

to down sample my data, but I currently have no idea how to get there, should i subset the data per station name first?

after running the ".groupby" line I could no only run the ".resample" line on my data and get an TypeError. it seems like my data is no longer seen as a date time index. I get the following error message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Conda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-12-68aebddc2221>", line 2, in <module>
    dftestR = dftest.resample('15min').last()
  File "G:\Conda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 1565, in resample
    return get_resampler_for_grouping(self, rule, *args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Conda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py", line 1287, in get_resampler_for_grouping
    resampler = tg._get_resampler(groupby.obj, kind=kind)
  File "G:\Conda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py", line 1404, in _get_resampler
    "Only valid with DatetimeIndex, "
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'
```

Am very new to coding. Will Appreciate all inputs.